# Displaying a MYSQL display set for a year with monthly totals

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have two tables, sales and costs, each with a costs fields, and a date field of type date.

The rest of the fields are not relevant for what I want to do.

I want to take the totals of each month, and display them together.

I am unsure if most of this should be done in SQL, if it must be one or several queries, of if I must manipulate the data in PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this two queries for each table.

```
SELECT month(date_field), SUM(cost_field)
FROM Costs 
GROUP BY month(date_field)

SELECT month(date_field), SUM(cost_field)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY month(date_field)
```

This is for each month.

Do you need the same list with totals for each year?

In that case it would be almost the same query

```
SELECT year(date_field), SUM(cost_field)
FROM Costs 
GROUP BY year(date_field)

SELECT year(date_field), SUM(cost_field)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY year(date_field)
```

Comment: Just one more question, how would I show just one particular month? For example to show all the purchases for the set months, january, febuary, without having to explicitly defined the date ranges?

Comment: Or, just for the moment to make it easier, how would you do the current month regardless of what month it is?

Comment: Actually, I think I need to make another question on dealing with the data in PHP, or should I edit this question?

Comment: you can add WHERE clause to your query. You shoud add "WHERE month(date_field) = 6" for June, 7 for July etc. If you want to get current month it would be "WHERE month(date_field) = month(getdate())"

Comment: It seems that you don't know about upvote/downvote system? Please, read faq. If answer is usefull you should upvote it.

Comment: Jacob, p.s. I think you should read some tutorials or a book on how to work with sql in php.

Comment: sorry, I did not realize I could vote. I have upvoted you. I actually have a quetsion, as it seems I was not thinking before. Your query only returns two columns, month(saledate) and SUM(cost). Per my questions though, I want to show purchases costs separate from sales costs. Should this still be two seperate queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with SUM() and GROUP BY in sql